# MailScanners: spamassassin vs spamd & clamav vs clamd

Tags: debian, email, sendmail

I'm trying to decide which method is better question for you today.

I'm running a Debian+Sendmail(w/TSL+SASL)+MailScanner+SpamAssassin+Clam setup.

I'm wondering which is a better way to execute my setup on a VPS which will eventually have some serious mail traffic. End goal is to conserve RAM and CPU. The two options are:

- Spamassassin vs the spamd daemon
- ClamAV (clamscan) vs clamd daemon

I've googled the topic quite a bit and have not really found any good direction. Can anyone please provide advice on which options would be best?